# How does Dask read from SQL Server in Python

Tags: python, odbc, dask, pyodbc

I have to use dask dataframe because my data is huge 150 million rows and 50,000 columns

I tried to use

```
conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                      'Server=DELL;'
                      'Database=DB;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;')
df_features = dd.read_sql_table(table="Features" , con=conn , index_col="ID")
```

I got this error

```
TypeError: read_sql_table() missing 1 required positional argument: 'uri'
```

So i tried this

```
df_features = dd.read_sql_table(table="Features" , uri="mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=Driver={SQL Server}; Server=DELL; Database=DB; Trusted_Connection=yes;", index_col="ID")
```

and got this error

```
OperationalError: (pyodbc.OperationalError) ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Neither DSN nor SERVER keyword supplied (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
```

how to connect to SQL Server in dask dataframe?

Comment: Can you connect to the database? `isql -v -k "<connection-string>"`

Comment: I can connect using the same connection string using Pandas dataframe but dask is not working

Comment: what is /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf ?

Comment: Can you try this? `uri="mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=Driver={SQL Server}; SERVER=DELL;DATABASE =DB;Trusted_Connection=yes;"`

Comment: it is the same i tried, and gave error

Comment: OperationalError: (pyodbc.OperationalError) ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Neither DSN nor SERVER keyword supplied (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)

Comment: Also, don't you need to provide user and password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Giorgos-Myrianthous is on the right lines: you need a URI, not some connection object. The format for this URI needs to be something that SQLalchemy can understand, so read their documentation to see how to format for ODBC.

Docs: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/mysql.html#module-sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql.pyodbc

The reason is, that Dask needs to be able to serialise and pass around tasks, but connection objects cannot be serialised. However, if you are working with threads only, you can pass a SQLalchemy engine object (this is in master).

Answer (score 1):

Windows ODBC Driver Manager requires no white-spaces between a keyword and `=`

---

The following should do the trick:

```
df_features = dd.read_sql_table(
    table="Features",
    uri="mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=my.db.server;DATABASE=DB;Trusted_Connection=yes;",
    index_col="ID"
)
```